# changing dynamic params in axios from data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, parameters, eloquent, axios

in laravel i have dynamic url like this:

```
api/product/all?page=2&per_page=15
```

page & per_page is dynamic and in future i'll add other property like price range,data &...
i hace this mehod for showing in my template:

```
    data: () => ({
        url:'./api/product/all',
        items: [],

        pagination: {
            total: '', 
            page_number:1,
            per_page: '2',
            total_page:'',
            from: '',
            last:'',
            to: '',
            current_page: ''
        },

    }),

    mounted : function(){
        this.getVueItems();
    },



    computed: {
        axiosParams() {
            const params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.append('per_page', this.pagination.per_page);
            params.append('page', this.pagination.page_number);
            return params;
        }
    },

    methods : {
        getVueItems: function(page){
            axios.get(this.url,{
                params: this.axiosParams
            }).then(response => {
                var vm = this;
                vm.items = response.data.data;
            });
        }
    },
```

as you see i create the params and computed this with axiosParams().
this is work but when i changing the data like (per_page),data will update but the params not.

```
<select v-model="pagination.per_page">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Don't you have any event on your ```<select>``` element? such as ```@change```?

Comment: i think its not necessary, because the data changed but not url not refresh

Comment: It's so strange! your data change if only ```getVueItems``` called. But you never call it, except in ```mounted()``` function

Comment: I'm new with vue, but in my knowledge we must using watch method in somewhere!!

Comment: or in this case i must using fetch(), but i dont know how i can!

Comment: Of course ```watch``` helps to keep parameters value updated but can't recall methods when things change. So you have to add ```@change``` event to your select element and call ```getVueItems``` on this event's triger.